# RMI IntHolder streamable - how to send it?

Tags: java, rmi, corba

I have problem with RMI. I want to use remote object with parameter IntHolder from org.omg.CORBA, but everytime when I do that I'm getting NoSerializationException. I know that class should implemented Sarializable interface, but in this case I cannot do that.

One point. In remote method parameter I must have IntHolder

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using RMI/IIOP.